# Can't add custom fonts to CKEditor 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

i know this question is probably asked alot ald, and i ald found many people asking this question. But somehow i still couldnt figure out for this to work. Im trying to add new custom fonts to my CKeditor for my MVC5 application. About a week ago, i added new fonts via config.js n it worked fine. But now, it just doesnt work anymore, it keeps showing my old fonts that i added from a week ago. I tried reinstall Ckeditor into my solution, clear my browser cache...etc. Also, i found out that even tho i remove ckeditor package from the solution, when i run the application, i can still use ckeditor so i think this might be a reason.
Here're my code:

### config.js

```
/**
     * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2018, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
     * For licensing, see https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
     */

    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        config.contentsCss = 'fonts.css'
        config.font_names = 'Khmer_OS;'
    };
```

### fonts.css :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Khmer_OS";
    src: local("Khmer_OS"), url("fonts/KHMEROS.TTF") format('opentype'); /*non-IE*/
}
```

Comment: "even tho i remove ckeditor package from the solution, when i run the application, i can still use ckeditor"  - "It is possible that you have more than one instance of CKEditor installed in your application because your setup looks correct and should work.

Comment: Please remember that CKEditor can auto-inline `contenteditable` elements and auto-create classic editoron `textareas` with class `ckeditor`. In order to fully remove CKEditor you should also remove the script reference to `ckeditor.js` in header. In order to clear cache properly, please see: https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache.